# Tag merge request [qboe] -> [quickbooks-online]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The tags [qboe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qboe) and [quickbooks-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quickbooks-online) appear to refer to the same thing and should probably be merged/synonymized.

Answer (score 1):

It's ...

**done**.

(Also what else seemed to need doing. <50 questions together)